# Document for C# client library of Visual Studio Team Service

Tags: azure-devops

I was looking at the c# .NET client for Team Services API
at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples

Where could I find a detailed document for this client library beside samples found in the above URL?

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*. Asking us to find documentation would clearly fall within that category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of API in the page you refer to: Rest API & SOAP API.

For SOAP-based client, the document can be found here: [Extending Team Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146(v=vs.120).aspx), and you can refer to this blog for how to use them: [TFS API Index Parts 1 To 37](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2011/05/18/tfs-api-index-parts-1-to-37/).

For REST-based HTTP client, I cannot find any detailed document for them. But you can get some more information from "Visual Studio\View\Object Browser" and this API is the same as [VSTS Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/basics), so you can also get some more information from that page.

Comment: I was looking at the REST-based HTTP client approach. Although I used DotPeek to look into the code, it isn't quite helpful and the XML document doesn't have much info. The reason I use this client library is to avoid manually mapping the JSON object to .NET. I wish they have swagger file for the REST API so that I can use the AutoRest tool in VisualStudio. Could you be able to suggest any other methods so that I could mapping the returned JSON to .NET object automatically? Thanks

Comment: @LxL There isn't any way to map the VSTS Json response to .NET automatically as I know, I'm afraid that you need to do it manually.